# C++ specializing variadic template inside of a variadic template

Tags: c++, templates

How do I specialize classes with variadic template parameters inside of classes with variadic template parameters? I.e.:

```
template < typename ... >
struct test_class
{
    template < typename ... >
    struct s { };
};

template < >
template < typename ... ts >
struct test_class< ts ... >::s< int > { }; // doesn't work
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename...>
struct OutsideS {
    // ...
};

template </* ... */>
struct OutsideS</* ... */> {
    // ...
};

template <typename... Types>
struct TestClass {
    template <typename... OtherTypes>
    using S = OutsideS<OtherTypes...>;
};
```

Specializing it in a nested way is not possible, but you can specialize the nested template somewhere else.